# Setting default editor in Octave 4.0/4.2.1 to Vim

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, octave, ubuntu-16.04

I'd like to use vim as my editor in Octave and I've tried following the steps on the [octave wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Vim) on this subject. My .octaverc file contains:

```
# Use vim as editor
edit mode async
EDITOR("xfce4-terminal -e 'vim %s'")
```

I've also tried using xterm instead of xfce4-terminal, gvim instead of vim, and the following .octaverc file:

```
# Use vim as editor
edit mode sync
edit home .
EDITOR('vim > /dev/tty 2>&1 < /dev/tty %s')
```

I can verify that the script has run when I start octave since EDITOR returns the same string. However, when I try to edit a file via e.g. the command

```
>> edit temp.m
```

I have the problem that the editor is not vim, it's no different than if I had a blank .octaverc file. I'm not sure what else to try. I've updated octave to version 4.2.1 and the problem persists. I'm on xubuntu (ubuntu 16.04) using vim 7.4.

Comment: "xfec4-terminal" should be "xfce4-terminal"

Comment: And there is a whole section "Vim as the default editor" on the wiki http://wiki.octave.org/Vim

Comment: Andy: thanks for catching the typo, however it doesn't change the behavior. Same is true if I use xterm. Also, that is the section of the wiki I am referring to. It's out of date and I'm unable to find other references.

Comment: It works as expected on my system (Debian GNU/Linux stretch, GNU Octave 4.3.0+) if I follow the two steps (for octave >=3.8.0) on the wiki. Btw, if you refer to some external resource, you should include a link to that source

Comment: @Andy Thanks, I've updated my question some and included the link. Which two steps are you referring to? I only see the wiki saying one thing about version 3.8

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in macOS. My solution is to add

EDITOR('vim')

to /usr/local/share/octave/site/m/startup/octaverc

Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with octave 6.1 on macOS. The only way I could get it to work was to use:

edit mode sync
edit home .
EDITOR('vim > /dev/tty 2>&1 < /dev/tty %s')

added to /usr/local/share/octave/site/m/startup/octaverc and NOT .octaverc in my local directory.